# Application needs to restart every time it's entered

Tags: android

I have an application with a splash screen. It shows the first time I run but then it never shows again. Is there anyway of making my application reset every time I start it?

Comment: make the splash screen the first activity..

Comment: If your application needs to be restarted every time its entered than its designed poorly and this is your actual problem. Furthermore: Your application *is* resetted every time its *started*.

Comment: I don't "need" to restart it every time, but I want because the splahscreen looks so cool! @theV0ID

Comment: Than see rekire's answer below. Adding `finish` to `onPause` should do the trick. However, this seems looks like a really bad idea of user interface design to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your activity will not been destroyed, when it goes into the background. Instead your app is just continues at this place where you left it. Just imagine that you switch between two activities you properly don't want to show in those cases the splash screen will been shown again. By default it would just continue your application until it is terminated in the background e.g. when the memory gets low.

However if you really want that behavior (which I would not suggest) then call in `onPause()`the method `finish()`. This will terminate your current instance, when your activity get into the background.

If you just want to show the splash screen on the app launcher icon click you should use the `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` option in the manifest, what also Lal pointed out in his answer. To detect that your application got started with the launcher icon you can check the intent.

On the first start just `onCreate()` will been called, on the second start (via the launcher) `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` will been called there you can check with `Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER.equal(intent.getAction())` if your app was opened with the launcher or not.

Answer (score 0):

Make the splashscreen Activity the first activity of your application as below

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` add this to the SplashScreen Activity

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

**UPDATE**

Add `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file inside those activities that you want to open only once.

Comment: I have already added this code, what I want is my application to reset every time it is started @Lal